# Python 3.6 - Regular Expression with

Tags: regex, python-3.x

The following code returns a dictionary of part numbers from a spreadsheet and works as intended.

```
import openpyxl, os, pprint, re

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('RiverbedInventory.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

max_row = sheet.max_row

inventory = {}

for row in range(1,max_row+1):
    prodName = sheet['G' + str(row)].value

    inventory.setdefault (prodName, {'count': -0})
    inventory[prodName] ['count'] += 1

pprint.pprint(inventory)
```

I'm trying to filter the results using a regular expression to only return part #s matching specific criteria (part #s that start with VCX in this case).  I keep getting "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object" failure messages. I've googled this quite a bit but can't find an answer.  Here's the regular expression code I'm using:

```
import openpyxl, os, pprint, re

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('RiverbedInventory.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

max_row = sheet.max_row

steelhead = re.compile(r'VCX-\d+-\w+')

inventory = {}

for row in range(1,max_row+1):
    prodCode = sheet['G' + str(row)].value

    inventory.setdefault (prodCode, {'count': -0})
    inventory[prodCode]['count'] += 1

pprint.pprint (steelhead.findall(inventory))
```

[working vs non-working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N44i6.jpg)

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the full error traceback? And also add some example lines from the CSV?

Comment: `inventory` is not a string, and you pass it in `steelhead.findall(inventory)` where `findall` expects a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `steelhead.findall(inventory)`, you pass a dictionary instead of a string. `re.findall` expects a string as the second argument.

You may use dictionary comprehension here:

```
print( {k: inventory[k] for k in inventory if steelhead.search(k)} )
```

See the [Python 3 demo](https://ideone.com/7UkUgR):

```
import re
inventory = {'UMTS-UNV-E': {'count':59}, 'VCX-020-E': {'count':2}, 'VCX-030-E': {'count':3}}
steelhead = re.compile(r'VCX-\d+-\w+')
print( {k: inventory[k] for k in inventory if steelhead.search(k)} )
```

Output: `{'VCX-030-E': {'count': 3}, 'VCX-020-E': {'count': 2}}`

Comment: Hello Wiktor,  thanks so much!  Your suggestion works mostly but only if it runs for part of the sheet.  There are 17,000+ rows in the sheet and the code will run up until row 5,092.  5,093 fails but there doesn't seem to be anything special about that row.  I updated the attached pic above "working vs non-working."

Comment: @MattSherman Try casting that value to string when reading: `prodCode = str(sheet['G' + str(row)].value)`

Comment: @WiktorStribzew - Bingo!  That worked.  It's odd that the previous way worked for a certain number of rows and then didn't but I'll take it.  Really appreciate your help.  Thanks